# IntelliJ Spring Gradle "Run all tests" not working (single test runs fine)

Tags: java, spring, testing, gradle, intellij-idea

I have a Spring Gradle Project with 4 Tests and the following build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.6.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

version = '0.0.1'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    //Rest Controller
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    //Lombok
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    //Tests
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testCompile 'com.h2database:h2'
    //Database
    compile("mysql:mysql-connector-java")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    //Authentication
    compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto' //e.g. PasswordEncoder
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security' //e.g. @PreAuthorize
    //ResourceAssembler
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas'
    //JWT Token generation
    compile("com.auth0:java-jwt:3.4.0")
}
```

I can start every test with "Run test" and it works great but when I try to "Run all tests" it fails with the message "Error running "All": No junit.jar"

I already tried adding any of the following dependencies but none resolved the issue:

```
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12


testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.4.2')
testRuntime('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.4.2')
```

I am using IntelliJ

Comment: Are you able to run using gradle using the command gradlew clean build ?

Comment: Yes but I am not sure whether I can see code coverage when running tests with that command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The classpath is derived from the dependencies of the module containing the test. The files are loaded from the working directory so it should be specified in the Run/Debug configuration for your tests. The following link explains how to configure it for your tests.
[Running JUnit tests in IntelliJ](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-unit-testing/running-tests-with-idea.html)

Also, I would want to check the test runner configuration in the IntelliJ IDE. Open the Preferences or Settings dialog window. Inspect the Gradle configuration and look for Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | Runner:

[image]

Here, select the Gradle test runner. Once configured, you can run your code with coverage and see if it helps.

Comment: thank you so much!!! That was exactly the setting that was wrong, after changing it to "Gradle Test Runner" from "Platform Test Runner" everything worked :D